WWII drama from 80s or early 90s
I am trying to find a WWII drama from 80s or early 90s taking place in a bombed out British city, I'm assuming London. 
One scene shows a group of boys, one of whom finds a live ammo round, playing in a bombed building. He uses a nail to fire the round and pretends to be shot by it, much to the dismay of the other boys. 
Another scene shows the residents having a rare fun afternoon watching a barrage balloon that has broken loose from its tether and is drifting aimlessly. 
I only saw a few scenes on tv and have been looking for it ever since.

Hope and Glory - 1987
I believe that "Hope and Glory" directed by John Boorman from 1987 is the film you are looking for.
The film stars Rice Edwards as Bill Rohan a 10 year old boy that lives in war torn London playing in the ruins and rubble of the bombings, pretending to be soldiers etc.

At one point Bill is "captured" as a spy and "threatened" with unexploded shells. 
One of the boys places a .303 bullet into a vice and hits it with a hammer and nail causing it fire and ricochet into a wall, he then pretends he was shot by it.
This can be seen at around 2:00 in the below clip.



His sister falls pregnant to a Canadian soldier during the film. 
There is a scene where a barrage balloon breaks free and has to be shot down by the home guard after causing damage to roofs. 
[
I loved this film and my favourite scene is where Bill goes to school, sees it has been bombed and runs down the street arms aloft shouting "Thank you Adolf"



